# Earphone is not working well, volume is very low in Galaxy SIII

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, volume

I have a Samsung Galaxy SIII. Please help me to find the problem. I cannot hear well when I receive phone calls. This problem started recently, before that, the earphone was working perfectly. Does that mean that I need to change the earphone or it is a matter of something that I need to do in the phone's options?

Comment: Stupid question, but just to be sure: Have you tried to increase the volume, while you are on a phone call? Android has different sound level settings for different activities (music, navigation, etc).

Comment: yes of course. when you put the volume to the maximum it is still very low. It was not like that two weeks ago.

Comment: Are you using an external earphone?

Comment: I have the exact same problem with LG G4! I even changed earphones but the issue persists! The thing is that it was like that from the begining

Answer (score 1):

This might seem silly, but I had this problem on my Razr Maxx HD and my solution was to use a canned air blower (with a thin straw) into the earphone jack.  It blew out ridiculous amounts of lint that must have been accumulating from the phone being in my pants pockets.

Answer (score 0):

If your phone is rooted, you can try to install Meltus' [Galaxy Volume Modifier](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=30057896&postcount=1). This is for the **Samsung Galaxy SIII International version ONLY**.

**Requirements:**

- An International Samsung Galaxy S III with Root Access and Busybox
- The ROM you're running must be a Samsung ROM (i.e. not CM)
- A knowledge of ADB, Fastboot and the flashing process, just in case.