# Can't hear people unless switched to speakerphone on Galaxy S4

Tags: audio, samsung-galaxy-s-4, calls, speakerphone

I have Samsung Galaxy S4 and I cannot hear callers unless the speakerphone is on. The caller can hear me well but there is only a very faint which is inaudible sound back.

I have gone to all the settings but it does not change anything.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Possibly related: [Earphone is not working well, volume is very low in Galaxy SIII](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/38121/16575)?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed mine using following instructions:

Go to **Settings → My Device → Sound → Samsung Applications → Press Call → Turn Off Noise Reduction**.

Comment: A user has suggested this for non-Samsung phone owners: https://android.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/179819

Comment: "My Device" does not exist on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Your earpiece speaker may be dead.  When you put your phone in speaker mode it uses different speaker(s).  Some people use a bluetooth earpiece to get around this, but if that's not something you want to do then you may want to check and see if your phone is still in warranty.

Also, depending on your phone you can try taking a small brush and cleaning around your earpiece speaker.  In some cases dust and other debris can collect and muffle the speaker, and considering how tiny these speakers and their speaker grills are (again, depends on your phone) it doesn'take much dust or debris to make it hard to hear.  When i worked for Verizon this was a common problem that we encountered on a daily basis.  Hopefully, that's all it is.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and tried  everything for two days, even did a factory reset, but nothing worked. Then I had an idea: the earpiece  could've been  blocked so I took an old toothbrush, brushed the ear piece for a minute to clear any debris and low, and behold it worked. So give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the plastic screen protector on the front of your phone, make sure it isn't covering your ear speaker.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many fixes but nothing worked. What worked was rolling a piece of hard paper to the size of headphone jack and inserting it to and fro several times until you see on screen headphones changing into ringer.

Answer (score 0):

Plugging in and out the headphones multiple times worked for me